# Morita equivalence and field extensions

Tags: representation-theory

Given a field K and an extension field L. Under what conditions is it true that algebras A and B are Morita equivalent K-algebras iff they are Morita equivalent L-algebras?

Comment: Could you provide the relative definition of Morita equivalence that you are using here?

Comment: I think the question is: When is the following true: A and B are Morita equivalent iff $L \otimes_K A$ and $L \otimes_K B$ are Morita equivalent.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Mare I think it is a good quesiont. And I have done the following work: If $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent over K. Then there is a progenerator $P$ of $A$-module, such that $End_A(P)=B$. And now I think $L \otimes P$ is a progenerator of $L \otimes A$-module. But I can't make sure whether $Hom_{L \otimes A}(L\otimes P, L\otimes P) \cong L \otimes B$. (hope to have some help for you)

Comment: Yes, A and B morita-equivalent should imply that $L \otimes A$ and $L \otimes B$ are morita equivalent. the other direction is more interesting I think.

Comment: @ Mare How to get $L \otimes A$ and $L \otimes B$ morita equivalent by $A$ and $B$ morita equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

*In general, the two notions are different:* For example, you might take for $A$ and $B$ two non-isomorphic central simple division algebras over $K$ and for $L$ a simultaneous splitting field for them. Then (by definition of splitting fields) $A\otimes_K L$ and $B\otimes_K L$ are matrix rings over $L$, hence Morita equivalent, but $A$ and $B$ are not, because you can recover them as the endomorphisms of the unique simple object in their categories of modules.

Comment: if you like Hanno's example, for sure you will enjoy the definition of the Brauer group of a field!